New ASP.NET Core 8 Web API error : connection refused
I am building an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. I got the following error in Postman when I ran it the first time:
GET https://localhost:5001/home


Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001

Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.39.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 173f13c0-5d2f-4fe0-9d75-df150fcc3fbf
Host: localhost:5001
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

From the following API method:
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello API!";
        }
    }
}

Very simple. The error baffled me. I checked all the usual culprits, HTTPS, proxy etc. nothing.

I noticed that the WeatherForecast example Controller and code were missing from the project I just created.  So, I decided to take a look at Program.cs to see what was there.  This is what I found:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast =  Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}

Strange code to put in Program.cs  It must be something new in .NET 8.  So I deleted all the unwanted code and got this:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.Run();

Now my simple little controller works!

that "strange code" is the minimal api implementation, introduced in net6.
